# What is your opinion about Community Server like platforms?

Tags: architecture, social-networking

If you can choose a platform to work with, when you build a new application, 
would you prefer to build it from scratch or use platform like Community Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking specifically about community server, the answer is custom from scratch.

If we are talking about in generic terms, it depends more on what you need and what products out there can provide the features you want and won't drive you to pulling your hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Iam with TheTXI on this one.  If you are talking specifically about CS, I would say build it from scratch.  However, there are other development frameworks that I have and do use for specific projects, however, there is a time and a place for all of them and that decision really has to be evaluated on a project-by-project basis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I haven't spent enough time getting to know CS, but it seems like a dog to me in terms of performance - very sluggish, especially compared to some of the much more popular and free products like phpBBS and the like.

Still looking for that free, open source, asp.net, forum software to use for some of my own projects - they maybe out there, but I haven't stumbled across one I like yet.

Comment: You might want to try YAF (Yet Another Forum). This is an ASP.NET open source forum. Never used it though!

Answer (score 0):

Subtext is also an option.  Community Server was once known as .TEXT.  Subtext is a variant of that project